# why the main method in java should be small letter(main) and not as caps letter(Main)?

Tags: java

is there is any specific reason in java, the main method should be a small letter

yes "Main" and "main"

This compiles

```
public class ManiMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

why this doesn't compile

```
public class ManiMethod {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one does compile, it just won't be recognized as a main class. The reason why its lowercase is because its the convention to write methods in lowerCamelCase and thus the main has to be as well.

Comment: Both compile. The second one *doesn't run*. The `main` method has to be lowercase because: 1) it's the java naming convention for methods (they should start with lowercase letter and be named camelCase), and 2) the designers of java language originally chose that name as a special one to be used as entry point for an application, so everything that is not `public static void main(String[])` won't be taken as an entry point.

Comment: @BackSlash ```public``` and ```static``` can be interchanged thus ```static public void main``` will also run

Comment: @Minn saying it won't be recognized as a "main class" is implying there is such a thing as a main class. There isn't. There is a main method, which can be used as entry point for the application. Any class can be called Main (whether or not it contains a main method) and can be considered a main-class (because of it's name), and every class can contain a main method of which the signature differs, meaning it still can't be used as entry point

Comment: @Mark correct, my point was that it has to be both `public` and `static`, that it has to be called `main` and it must have a `String[]` argument. As you correctly say, order of access modifiers doesn't matter as long as the meaning is the same to the compiler and the language supports it :)

Comment: You say the second example won't compile. What error did you get that makes you believe it won't compile?

Comment: @Stultuske https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: @Minn which contains a reference to the Main-Class header, which is not the same as the concept of a 'main class'

Comment: It is exactly what a main class is. The main class is a class specified in the main-class attribute that contains a main method. The class is the entrypoint specification.

Comment: So where can I find the configuration of the main method in the Java environment is just curious to know.

Answer (score 3):

The second snippet most definitely compiles - it just doesn't run because it doesn't have a `main` method.

Why `main` and not `Main`? Because that's what the language's designers decided. [Section 12.1.4 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) specifies how exactly the `main` method's signature should be defined.

Comment: I was searching for the section! This is the only valid answer for this question.

Comment: "won't run" is not the same as "can't use that method as entry point"

Comment: this is the correct answer. It's the chosen convention according to the Java Language Specification, linked in the answer

Answer (score 1):

> The `main` is the method called when a Java application begins. **Keep in mind that Java is case-sensitive**. Thus, `Main` is different from `main`.

You can find the more detailed explanation [here](http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/java/why-does-main-method-have-to-be-static.php)

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive. "Main" is not the main method. If you compile and run using Main it is not working.

```
 Error: Main method not found in class q1, please define the main method as:
     public static void main(String[] args)
 or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Answer (score 1):

`Main` and `main` will be two different methods if both are present in any class. Whenever you try to run any class say `TestClass` using `java TestClass`, then JRE will search for the method with name `main(String[] arg)`. Else it will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all Java is case-sensitive, "Main" and "main" are different for Java.
Secondly, Java was inspired by C/C++ which also uses the main() function as a starting point for a program.

Java will accept any function names even Main() but will specifically look for static main() method as the starting point of program.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrect.  This code:

```
public class ManiMethod {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

will compile fine.  It won't run as a Java program though.

In general, uppercase vs lowercase naming conventions, are just that, conventions.  There's nothing stopping you from giving methods names that start with uppercase letters.  Your second code block will compile just fine.

Then there's the question of if java can run this class.  It can not, because the definition of a class that Java can run is one that has a static method named "main", which is different than a method named "Main".

If you combine your two class definitions, so you have two methods, one named "Main" and one named "main", it will both compile and run.  The method named "main" will be the method that gets executed.

Comment: "it won't run". Sure it will, it just won't use that method as entry point

Comment: I said it won't run "as a java program".  As  I go on to explain, Java won't run it in and of itself.  Sure, it could be a second class that some `main()` ends up calling.

Answer (score -1):

Because those are the rules.

The rules also include that it must be static, public and accept a single parameter of type String[] (I.e. an array of String).

Since java is case sensitive Main is completely different to main.

There is also a convention (some would say standard) that classes start with a capital letter and methods start with a lower case method. So to extend your question to the extreme, you might as well be asking why isn't it called "abcde" instead of main?

As a result of all the above (and no doubt more) the developers of the java runtime environment elected to call the method that is the entry point for a java program `main`.

Comment: it doesn't accept a parameter of type string, it accepts a parameter of type string array. There is a huge different in both

Comment: Thanks @Mark, Good pickup I've edited the post... you should have edited it and for some reputation points! I'll upvote your comment as a consolation.

Comment: Yes, I can understand how programming is designed. I just want to understand the essence of the java and it desinig.. can you explain where and how can I find the above details which you confirmed in the answer.